# Specified cast is not valid (xamarin.android)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
namespace Quiz_App
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = false)]
    public class MainActivity : Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity
    {
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;
        
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            toolbar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar);

            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            SupportActionBar.Title = "TOPICS";
            Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar actionBar = SupportActionBar;
            actionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.menuaction);
            actionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        
    }
}
```

When I try to run the above xamarin code I get the error System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'.

How do i resolve this.

Comment: It's good that you provided the code, properly formatted, and that you provided the error message, but you didn't tell us where in the code the exception is thrown. Given that you are performing a cast on the line that sets `toolbar`, I'm guessing that it's there but we shouldn't have to guess. If it is that line then it means that `FindViewById` is not returning an `Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar` object, so you should be first checking to see what it is returning. You can then determine whether it's the return value or the cast that is the problem.

Comment: The error is coming at  the toolbar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar); line.Usually happens when the program is deploying to the emulator.

Comment: So what type is returned by that method when the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the element `Toolbar` in file `toolbar.axml` in `layout` folder is:

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

not

```
android.widget.Toolbar
```

For example:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```